# convert xaml icon to svg

Tags: xaml, svg

I am working on convert silverlight project to html5, one task is to convert xaml icon to svg? I see some solution on how to convert svg to xaml, but I can find anything about the reverse conversion. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: xaml icon? u mean something like appbar symbol icons?

Comment: This [online tool](http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-svg) claims to do it. I have not tried it